# SSH to vSphere VPS via TOR

Tags: onion-routing, ssh, vps

Is it possible to set up vSphere VM so one will be able to connect to it via SSH using an onion domain name?

For example:

```
ssh user@s4k4ceiapwwgcm3mkb6e4diqecpo7kvdnfr5gg7sph7jjppqkvwwqtyd.onion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a working case - you just need to tune your DNS **on the client machine** the right way! To achieve what you want you need to set up a local DNS server, I'm using BIND - you can use anything you want, and on that server you're redirecting the dot-onion zone to Tor's built-in resolver! Just make it, put your server into your operating system's list - and it will work! I did it like a thousand times in years - not a single fail!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why it would fail.

Any traffic that exits the onion router, should feel and behave the same , be it a HTTPS server or an SSH server.

(Don't ask me how, I'm a n00b. I just don't see any reason why it would fail.)